# Raphael: How to add/remove or show/hide Paper

Tags: javascript, raphael

I see Raphael has a `Paper.remove()` function which removes the paper from the dom, but does it have a `Paper.waitPutItBack()` function that I'm not seeing? I realize I could manipulate the svg object directly, or put it inside a div and manipulate that to avoid vml troubles, but it seems like if there is a native remove-from-dom function there should also be a native add-to-dom function I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't: the `remove` function is a deletion, with recursive deletions of nodes and event listeners.

```
R.prototype.remove = function () {
    eve("raphael.remove", this);
    this.canvas.parentNode && this.canvas.parentNode.removeChild(this.canvas);
    for (var i in this) {
        this[i] = typeof this[i] == "function" ? R._removedFactory(i) : null;
    }
};
```

You can however hide the DOM node of the paper container by setting the display property to none, and expect everything to work when you display as block again.  For example, hit the play button and then quickly click through toggle to show the moving animation.: http://jsfiddle.net/Cy8DQ/2/

Comment: Aw too bad. Yeah I'll just control the parent node.